# Git overwrite production branch with origin branch

Tags: git

So for whatever reason we named the master branch to be release for this application. It cannot be renamed due to issues with AWS. What happened is that we tried to change it to master then ssh'ed into the server to deploy and changed it to master and broke some connections. So I then went into the server, changed the branch to release and restarted the server. Problem quasi-solved. It fixed the underlying issue but it's not loading some JavaScript that is on origin.

There is:
production release (what's live)
origin release

In my terminal I'm on origin release and do git push production release. I end up getting "Updates were rejected because the top of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart".

So I do a git pull production release and this removes my app>assets>javascripts>import folder and everything in it. Then I have to do a git reset --hard origin/release to get everything back.

I thought I could do a git push -f production release then when I'm on origin release but I get "[remote rejected] release -> release (non-fast-forward)".

Any idea on how I can make the remote production branch match the origin branch?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make your current branch a child of `origin/release` with

`git merge --no-ff -s ours origin/release`

The resulting merge commit then can be pushed over origin/release.

What does this do:

- `git merge` makes a new merge commit of your current branch and the argument
- `--no-ff` tells git you don't want to do a fast-forward (i.e. just switch to the "newer" version) and forces it to make a merge commit
- `-s ours` forces a merge strategy that just keeps your current branch contents, so your result will technically be child of `origin/release` even though it actually contains none of its changes

Note that this will break many assumptions people usually have, such as "children of commit X contain changes done in commit X".